# How to solve the signal SIGABRT thread in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new to Ionic and Xcode Development. when i’m trying to build ios app through ionic 3, in xcode i facing the problem while i click the build…it showing a thread as (signal SIGABRT)…How to resolve this…?

[image]

Comment: It's too hard to guess the actual reason.We need more details. Is it crashing after you added any new plugin. Or is it failing at the very first time, you try to run. ?

Comment: No. I  already Export Android app using this Backup. but its notify Thread. when run in simulator its open home screen then goto error line. @MaheswaranRavisankar

Comment: Open safari, and try to inspect the simulator's webview. May be there can be some clue.